# Configuring c3p0 in jBoss standalone.xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss, c3p0

I need to configure the below hibernate configuration in jBoss 'standalone.xml' file. Could you please advise how to configue in jBoss.

I am using JBoss AS 7.1 as Application Server and MySQL DB

**Configuration:-**

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout" value="120000"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="20"/>
```

Comment: A simple google search could get 100 results: One such is https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration?_sscc=t

Comment: I could find only few like pool-size etc.. But I don't know how to configure the following configuration.  hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay, hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts, hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure, hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment, hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period, hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery

Comment: Those would become the similar properties.. on top of configuration.

Comment: Thank You. Am using "jboss-as-7.0.2.Final" version. Any version specific for this c3p0 configuration. I tried various ways but its not working. Could you please share any c3p0 configuration examples for the following. "hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" "hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts".

Comment: Hey Grace, add the properties similar to how you have in question. Let me know if that doesn't works..there is only the above way for additional properties on data source config.

Comment: i have a similary question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441995/how-to-configurate-c3p0-to-use-datasource-url-for-connection-at-the-oracle-datab but i was trying to configure c3p0 in the persistence.xml file from the war, and then in then in the *-ds.xml file be used by the ds, but no luck so far