# How to configure C3P0 to use datasource URL for connection at the oracle database in jboss AS7

Tags: oracle, jboss, datasource, c3p0

We are having trouble to configure c3p0 in jboss. There are two configurations files, and we don't know which we have to change:

Jboss datasource app-ds.xml:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/TestJNDI" pool-name="TestPool" use-ccm="false">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@server_test:port:database</connection-url>
        <connection-property name="schema">schema</connection-property>
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
        <pool>
                <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>400</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>pass</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        </validation>
        <statement>
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>   
</datasources>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="Oracle">
        <description>Oracle database connection</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>entity1</class>
        <!-- entities -->
        <class>entityN</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:/TestJNDI"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>  
            
            <!-- Important -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the log:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for Oracle
WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'AppTestEAR.ear/AppTest.war#Oracle'
INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Oracle
    ...]
INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver at URL: null
INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000046: Connection properties: {autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
INFO  [com.mchange.v2.log.MLog] (MSC service thread 1-8) MLog clients using log4j logging.
INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry] (MSC service thread 1-8) Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource] (MSC service thread 1-8) Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@20860e3b [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@8b71134e [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2zkodt9o11wh4uo1mijhxn|327556d1, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 300, initialPoolSize -> 3, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 180, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 200, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 20, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@d6b12b99 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2zkodt9o11wh4uo1mijhxn|2c53cfe3, jdbcUrl -> null, properties -> {autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2zkodt9o11wh4uo1mijhxn|4fcb6c, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-3) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1b6cdb87 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-3) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1b6cdb87 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
```

The problem is at:

```
HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver at URL: null
```

We want use the credentials (the URL) provided in the datasource in the jboss (business requirement),

So the question is: How to configure c3p0 to use datasource URL for connection at the oracle database in jboss AS7?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but why do you want to use c3p0? You already have a connection pool in JBoss, why not stick with that? If so you need to add some options to configure it in the same way as c3p0, but then you are done.

Comment: There are no stupid questions, there are stupids that don't ask ;). Anyway, thanks for the question, actually the webapp (war) has some troubles of memory and c3p0 has a very good logging and can resolve problems of connections opened but not closed better (imho) than the default pool connection of jboss. But you have a point, maybe us would have to use the jboss_cp. Also, i want to add to c3p0 some "cache" framework to optimize more the db queries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what's going on is that the DataSource is being constructed according to the config in `persistence.xml` and some of the JDBC-standard properties (e.g. `minPoolSize`, `maxPoolSize`) are being overridden by settings in `app-ds.xml`.

I think the main issue is that you do not configure the JDBC url in `persistence.xml`. (c3p0's `jdbcUrl` is not is JDBC-standard property, so `app-ds.xml`is not setting it.) You should add to `persistence.xml` something like:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@server_test:port:database</property>
```

`user` and `password` also appear not to be set. Add to `persistence.xml` something like:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
```

(To see what settings have and have not taken, scroll right to see the config information on the log line beginning `Initializing c3p0 pool...`)

I'd try removing as much as possible from the `app-ds.xml`, so you don't confusingly have config in two places. You might be able to get away with...

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/TestJNDI" pool-name="TestPool" use-ccm="false" />
</datasources>
```

...but maybe not.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Like i post in the questions, the jdbcUrl, user/pass are configured in the datasource by bussiness requirements. So the question is: "how is configured the persistence.xml to use c3p0 with the database credentials in the jboss datasource?", thanks :)

Comment: I think that if you want to configure that stuff in `app-ds.xml`, you'll have to stick to whatever Connection pool JBoss uses internally or by default. JBoss would have to translate that configuration to c3p0's configuration properties, which I doubt JBoss knows how to do. If you want c3p0, you can configure the authentication info in `properties.xml` or in a dedicated c3p0 config file (e.g. `c3p0.properties`), but probably not from  `app-ds.xml`.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no way to configure c3p0 in the *-ds.xml files, but anyway, tomorrow i'll start a bounty for this answer, thank you (again) for the feedback :)

Comment: (i just noticed that my prior comment says `properties.xml` where what i meant was `persistence.xml`. sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add in hibernate config you can connect to datasource as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
        <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
    <mapping class="com.study.vo.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you touch hibernate.cfg.xml?  You could add something like

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory> name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1521:sid</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">u</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">p</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">30</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>      
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```